# Is there a way to have two docs in Docusaurus 2?

Tags: javascript, documentation, docusaurus

As I know, Docusaurus supports customized pages, but is there a way to have two docs in one Docusaurus project?

The original Navbar items have:

- Docs
- Blog
- ...

I want to have something like this:

- Docs 1
- Docs 2
- Blog
- ...

I know I can make many subfolders just in one doc, but for some reason, I want a two Docs structure, which gives me a cleaner way to access docs.

**If Docusaurus cannot offer this feature currently, I want to ask is there other documentation frameworks offer this feature?**

Comment: This is officially documented here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to use the [plugin-content-docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs).

First, create the other `docs` folder, like `docs`, `docs-api`, `docs-system`.

**(1)** In your `docusaurus.config.js` file, configure your "default" docs:

```
(module.exports = { // start of the module.export declaration
[…]

    presets: [
        [
          '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
          {
            docs: {
              routeBasePath: 'docs',
              path: 'docs',
              sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
              lastVersion: 'current',
              onlyIncludeVersions: ['current'],
            },
            theme: {
              customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
            },
          },
        ],
      ],

[…] 
}); // end of the module-export declaration
```

**(2)** Now, the **magic!**: in the same file, configure your other documents:

```
(module.exports = { // start of the module.export declaration
[…]

plugins: [
    […]
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: 'docs-api',
        path: 'docs-api',
        routeBasePath: 'docs-api',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
      }, 
    ],
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: 'docs-system',
        path: 'docs-system',
        routeBasePath: 'docs-system',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
      }, 
    ],
],

[…]
}); // end of the module-export declaration
```

**(3)** Now you probably want these documents in your NavBar, right? So add then!

```
(module.exports = { // start of the module.export declaration
[…]

navbar: {
  hideOnScroll: true,
  title: 'your title',
  logo: {
    alt: '',
    src: 'img/favicon.ico',
  },
  items: [
    {
      to: '/docs/Intro',    // ./docs/Intro.md
      label: 'Docs Title',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/docs/`,
    },
    {
      to: '/docs-api/Intro',    // ./docs-api/Intro.md
      label: 'API',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/docs-api/`,
    },
    {
      to: '/docs-system/Introducao',  // ./docs-system/Intro.md
      label: 'My System',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/docs-system/`,
    },
  ],
},

[…]
}); // end of the module-export declaration
```

---

**IMPORTANT**

Sometimes you will modify your `docusaurus.config.js` and will not "work", so close the docusaurus `service` (just Ctrl+C in your terminal/power shell) and restart it -- I could have saved a few hours if a had known this before.

**If you don't have the plugin-content-docs plugin, just install it:**

> npm install --save @docusaurus/plugin-content-docs

---

**ROADMAP**

I had a hard time figuring this out. What I did was download the whole docusaurus project, get the website part, trim everything that I did not need and this is what I got.

---

**REFERENCES** (Update 2022/03/02)

https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance

Comment: This answer deserves more credit, THANK YOU!!

Comment: You saved me so much time!

Comment: Thank you. Gave me the right direction. I had to also use [docsPluginId](https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#navbar-doc-link) with `docId` in order for this to work in the navbar.

Comment: This is officially documented here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance

Comment: Note that additional instances need to point toward unique docs, aka, make sure you specify unique sidebar-<subinstance>.js files for each instance.

Answer (score 8):

This solution worked for me. Using the 'autogenerated' sidebar in Docusaurus v2.0.0-beta.15

sidebars.js

```
/** @type {import('@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs').SidebarsConfig} */

const sidebars = {

  // tutorialSidebar: [{type: 'autogenerated', dirName: '.'}],
  newone: [{type: 'autogenerated', dirName: 'newone'}],  // foldername
  newtwo: [{type: 'autogenerated', dirName: 'newtwo'}],  // foldername

};

module.exports = sidebars;
```

docusaurus.config.js

```
      navbar: {
        title: 'My Site',
        logo: {
          alt: 'My Site Logo',
          src: 'img/logo.svg',
        },
        items: [
          // {
          //   type: 'doc',
          //   docId: 'intro',
          //   position: 'left',
          //   label: 'Tutorials',
          // },

          {
            type: 'docSidebar',  // docSidebar
            position: 'left',
            sidebarId: 'newone', // foldername
            label: 'NEWONE',     // navbar title
          },
          {
            type: 'docSidebar',  // docSidebar
            position: 'left',
            sidebarId: 'newtwo', // foldername
            label: 'NEWTWO',     // navbar title
          },

          {to: '/blog', label: 'Blog', position: 'left'},
          {
            href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
            label: 'GitHub',
            position: 'right',
          },
        ],
      },
```

Your docs folder:

```
docs/
    newone/
        intro.md
    newtwo/
        intro.md
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thanks

Comment: This works great but, is there a way to avoid adding labels to navbar? skipping the label still adds it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this way and it's working.

**[Edit 1]**: But when I select API then both API and Docs in Navbar becomes green. Can you tell us what's the reason behind this [@Yangshun Tay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1751946/yangshun-tay) and can you suggest the edit for that?

**[Edit 2]**: I read the documentation, it's written in [@docusaurus/theme-classic](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/theme-classic), if we set `activeBasePath` property then links with that common path (`docs` in this case) will have active attribute.

sidebar.js

```
module.exports = {
    someSidebar: {
        Docusaurus: ['doc1', 'doc2'],
        Features: ['doc3']
    },
    someOtherSidebar: {
        Test: ['mdx']
    }
};
```

docusaurus.config.js

The navbar links are like this -

```
links: [
    {
        to: 'docs/doc1',
        // activeBasePath: 'docs', // [Edit 3]
        label: 'Docs',
        position: 'left'
    },
    {
        to: 'docs/mdx',
        label: 'API',
        position: 'left'
    },
]
```

Folder structure of docs folder is like this -

```
docs
├── docs1.md
├── mdx.md
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether you're using v1 or v2, the `sidebars.js` configuration can contain [multiple keys](https://v2.docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar#sidebar-object), each having its own sidebar.

Comment: I think he meant something else, with the help of `sidebars.js` we can create multiple partitions inside the `/docs` route. But what he is asking for is to create two separate docs folder **API**  and **docs** which have the same functionality as docs. It is present in v1 of docusaurus navbar.

Comment: He meant navbar

Comment: Navbar items are just hrefs and you are free to put anything you want in it.

Comment: What if I want a News page which is exactly similar to blog page, is it possible to create one in v2? I tried by creating a folder named **news** and moving the `.mdx` files inside it. It didn't work

Comment: Ja! What GermaVinsmoke said is exactly what I mean. @YangshunTay I understand Navbar items are just hrefs and I can customize it. But the doc generation is automatic, including all the routes and the sidebar. I can create a new PAGE and put on navbar, but how can I create another new doc which has a different sidebar?

Comment: @EchoYang Try my solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the doc type in docusaurus config. I think the "to" type is for pages not docs.

To make the sidebar correct, you need to also set the activeSidebarClassName value in the config to let it know which sidebar (among those you exported in the sidebars.js) you want to use for this doc.

```
activeSidebarClassName: 'navbar__link--active',
```

https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/themes/configuration#navbar-doc-link

Answer (score 0):

Setting up Docusaurus to be multi-instance spans changes across many files. To make it easier to set up, I've created a base install with all the necessary changes to go multi-instance, and have released it as a GitHub template.

Fork it here:
[**mg0716/docusaurus-multi**](https://github.com/mg0716/docusaurus-multi)

Many of the changes in this repo were a result from [@d-kastier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734097/d-kastier)'s original [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/4573790).

Very open to feedback and pull requests, so feel free to give it a shot!