# Docusarus v2 - ¿How to add new tabs for Doc in NavBar?

Tags: docusaurus

I recently started using ** Docusaurus2 ** for tech notes in college.

I am interested in creating one or more `Docs2`, `Docs3`.

I have seen that it is a pluging that has to be duplicated. But with my config, it doesn't generate index.html for additionals tabs.

This is my folder list for docs: `docs`, `dev`. And in the `dev` folder some markdown files.

My docusaurus.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
  title: 'ApuntEs',
  tagline: 'The tagline of my site',
  url: 'https://your-docusaurus-test-site.com',
  baseUrl: '/',
  onBrokenLinks: 'throw',
  onBrokenMarkdownLinks: 'warn',
  favicon: 'img/favicon.ico',
  organizationName: 'srlopez', // Usually your GitHub org/user name.
  projectName: 'apuntes', // Usually your repo name.
  themeConfig: {
    navbar: {
      title: 'ApuntEs',
      logo: {
        alt: 'ApuntEs',
        src: 'img/logo.svg',
      },
      items: [
        {
          to: 'docs/',
          activeBasePath: 'docs',
          label: 'Docs',
          position: 'left',
        },
        {to: 'dev/', activeBasePath: 'dev', label: 'Dev', position: 'left'},
        {to: 'blog', label: 'Blog', position: 'left'},
        {
          href: 'https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus',
          label: 'GitHub',
          position: 'right',
        },
      ],
    },
    footer: {
   // omited
    },
  },
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          id: 'doc',
          sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebars.js'),
         },        
        blog: {
          showReadingTime: true,
        },
        theme: {
          customCss: require.resolve('./src/css/custom.css'),
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      "@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs",
      {
        id: 'dev',
        path: "dev", // Path to data on filesystem, relative to site dir.
        routeBasePath: "dev", // URL Route.
        include: ["**/*.md"],
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebarsDev.js'),
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

It looks nice, but tab `Dev` doesn't work. The `index.html` is not generated on `npx docusaurus build`
and this is the version I am using.

```
npx docusaurus --version
2.0.0-alpha.70
```

May some one help me?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Found a solution?

Comment: Kinda late, but this should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097