# How to create an index page with links to multiple dynamic files with Docusaurus?

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

Assuming the following file structure, if I want to link from `directory_1/file_1.md` to an index page containing links to all files in `directory_2`:

1. Would I need to create the index page in `directory_2` or can I just link to the directory some way?
2. If I need to create the index page, can I set it up so it is dynamic, and will change as the other files in `directory_2` change?

```
directory_1
    file_1.md
directory_2
    flavor_1.md
    flavor_b.md
    flavor_4.md
```

I have tried linking directly to `directory_2`, but I end up getting a 404 error.

Comment: I believe that you want a way of [referencing other documents](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-markdown-features#referencing-other-documents). I don't know how to make it automatically… So you probably will need to create it manually.  Obs: before I thought that you want  [two docs in docusaurus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097).

Comment: @D.Kastier yes, I essentially want to link to a "category" listed in `sidebars.js`. An analog is using Read the Docs you could create the index page and use * wildcard to collect all files in the directory for links.