# How to reference files outside of Docusaurus root folder

Tags: jekyll, documentation, documentation-generation, static-site, docusaurus

My team and I are looking to implement a documentation system that allows engineers to put markdown files within a specified folder in each of their service root directories.  Since we are in a monorepo, we'd like to have a process that goes through and aggregates all of the necessary markdown files and statically generates a final site.

We'd love to use Docusaurus to handle this task; however, we are running into an issue where it seems unable to serve files that are outside of the directory that it is "installed" (where its config is/where it's invoked).

Example directories:

```
/docs/ <- docusaurus is in this folder
/service/_docs <- these are the markdown files we'd like to pull from
```

Docusaurus is able to (a) resolve the paths (b) writes the json metadata files. I can tell because I've added logging + I see the .json files that are generated in the .docusaurus folder.

We are using the plugin-content-docs and would love to avoid having to write our own plugin:

```
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: 'foo',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'service', '_docs'),
        routeBasePath: 'service'
      },
    ],
```

Comment: Have you had any luck regarding this? We also looking to integrate Docusaurus inside a monorepo.

Comment: I had some success. You may want to look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/3625171)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need to configure according to [Docusaurus docs](https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance):

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/preset-classic',
      {
        docs: {
          // id: 'default', // omitted => default instance
          path: 'docs',
          routeBasePath: '/',
          // ... other options
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  plugins: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: 'service',
        path: '../service/docs', // <<-- relative path from the docusaurus folder
        routeBasePath: 'docs/service',
        // ... other options
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```