# My Docusaurus docs multi-instance ended up with two navbar links that go to the same intro.md file, but I don't know why

Tags: docusaurus

I'm making a Docusaurus site with two separate sets of documentation. One set of documents is for our website content creators and the other is for site development documentation.

I followed instructions on the Docusaurus site for implementing Docs Multi-instance: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance

1. I already have a /docs folder. I created a new /dev folder on the same level. Screenshot: [two documentation directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dtKx.png)
2. I installed the docs plugin according to instructions here: https://docusaurus.io/docs/api/plugins/@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs
3. I have the original docs instance from preset-classic. Screenshot: [preset-classic code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2TOf.png)
4. I added a line for the additional docs by adding plugin info to the docusaurus.config.js file. Screenshot: [plugin code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnRtE.png)
5. Both /docs and /dev have a markdown file called intro.md. The site loads but the two nav items both point to the intro.md file that's in /docs.
6. I changed the name of the intro.md file in /dev to devintro.md. After that change, I don't get an error in terminal, but the content isn't visible on the docusaurus site anymore. I just see the favicon and nothing else.

Here's a screenshot from inspector: [inspector view of nav links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg5yr.png)

Has anyone else successfully gotten a multidocs instance running in Docusaurus? How can I have my nav items point to the landing page within each directory? Am I missing a step?

Comment: Check this: [Is there a way to have two docs in Docusaurus 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097)

Comment: maybe you have `slug: /` in your intro.md's yaml?

Answer (score 0):

You created something like this to have another docs instance.

```
  plugins: [
    [
      '@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs',
      {
        id: 'logic',
        path: 'logic',
        routeBasePath: 'logic',
        sidebarPath: require.resolve('./sidebarsLogic.js'),
        // ... other options
      },
    ],
  ],
```

If you don't have another instance declared like that in your config file, I recommend that you follow this tutorial: https://docusaurus.io/docs/docs-multi-instance

Then the **id:'logic'** is your plugin id.

You add to the navbars like the following.

```
items: [
          ... existing navbar items. 
          {
            type: 'doc',
            docsPluginId: 'logic',
            docId: 'intro',
            position: 'left',
            label: 'Logic',
          },
```

Note that the **docsPluginId** is the **id** mentioned above.

That's it!