# Providing different variants/flavors of content

Tags: docusaurus

I'm using Docusaurus to write tutorials for my company's platform (https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-samples-docs/docs/intro), and I'm providing multiple language/IDE variants for each tutorial. Right now, the variants are nested under each tutorial in the sidebar, e.g.:

```
Tutorials
  - Simple Viewer
    - Node.js & VSCode
    - .NET 6 & VSCode
    - .NET 6 & VS2022
  - Hubs Browser
    - Node.js & VSCode
    - .NET 6 & VSCode
    - .NET 6 & VS2022
```

Which seems a bit messy...

Does Docusaurus provide any way to perhaps have a dropdown that the user could use to select a specific variant/flavor of whatever doc page is selected in the sidebar? And if something like this is not available, what would be the recommended way of implementing such feature?

Comment: I think that you could use [multiple docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097), or maybe [multiple code languages](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/code-blocks#multi-language-support-code-blocks) in you documents.

Comment: Thanks! I'm already using code tabs in [my docs](https://petrbroz.github.io/forge-samples-docs/docs/tutorials/simple-viewer/setup#new-project) but that feels a bit hacky. The Docs Multi-instance approach looks promising though.