# I can't get a page to show on Docusaurus. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: terminal, localhost, docusaurus, static-pages

I've been configuring a local site I built via Docusaurus, and I can't get to show the **About** page. I made sure the links are correct, but I keep on getting an error. I feel like I just overlooked something very simple, but I honestly don't know much about this.

[Here's the local site saying "Page not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EEYY.png)

[Here's where the about file is located inside the folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lyGl.png)

[Here's the error I got in the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwOak.png)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I am adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097) to try to help you.

**1.** Move your `about.md` file to the `docs` folder.

This way, it will compile correctly.

**2.** In your `docusaurus.config.js`, modify to look similar to this. This will put a link in the `navbar` to the page `about.md`.

```
(module.exports = { // start of the module.export declaration
[…]

navbar: {
  hideOnScroll: true,
  title: 'your title',
  logo: {
    alt: '',
    src: 'img/favicon.ico',
  },
  items: [
    {
      to: '/docs/Intro',    // ./docs/Intro.md
      label: 'Portifolio',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/docs/`,
    },
    {
      to: '/docs/about',    // ./docs/about.md
      label: 'About me',
      position: 'left',
      activeBaseRegex: `/docs/about`,
    },
  ],
},

[…]
}); // end of the module-export declaration
```