# docusaurus - dynamic sidebar content based on access level

Tags: docusaurus

I'm looking at docusaurus for implementing documentation site. We want to have different access level -  If you're not logged in, you can only see limited pubic doc, if you logged in then you can see more doc, and if you're admin you can see even more doc.

Is this something we can do via docusaurus? It seems we can implement access control to the site by path-level but I cannot find way to have different sidebar content for different access level.

https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/issues/958#issuecomment-1099591676

Comment: It should be possible, but you need to known/learn about ReactJS, and use it with your docussaurus. Check [this reference](https://www.zacfukuda.com/blog/react-auth0).

Comment: @D.Kastier I know react and I am able to implement access control on path-level, however my question is how we can have different sidebar for different access level, which I don't think above article addresses.

Comment: I did a search and [found this](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/discussions/7585), and if I understand correctly it is not possible, in a easy way, to achieve what you want... Maybe you can workaround using [two docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68162605/5734097) ?