Multiple doc paths with one instance in Docusaurus
I'm porting a doc site to Docusaurus. There are 5 products that each have specific documentation, and I'd like there to be a path for each product (mysite.com/product-1/, mysite.com/product-2/, and so on).
This is what I mean:
/product-1
  -- feature 1
    -- content
    -- content
    -- content
  -- feature 2
    -- content
    -- content
    -- content
/product-2
  -- feature 1
    -- content
    -- content
    -- content
  -- feature 2
    -- content
    -- content
    -- content
[etc]

I know that you can start multiple instances for versioning but don't need separate versioning per product, I just want to be able to group the docs in separate folders, associate a sidebar with each group, and have a custom URL path - for example, all product-1 docs would have path mysite.com/product-1/ and use the product-1 sidebar.
Anyone know how I might achieve this?

Is this helpful for you?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60783595/is-there-a-way-to-have-two-docs-in-docusaurus-2?rq=2
